# Is there a better way to find the max count in a table

Tags: t-sql

```
select NV.PHG
From Nhanvien NV
Group by NV.phg
Having count(nv.Manv) >= all (select count(NV.MANV from nhanvien nv group by nv.MANV))
```

I'm finding a better way to find the 'max count' NV of a PHG ( in this example ) . I think, we meet this case all the time when we do SQL, i should've a better way .
Thanks for reading this :)

Comment: What is the purpose of the column NV.MANV in your query? Your description of what you are trying to do doesn't even mention this column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the group with the largest number of members you can use this:

```
SELECT TOP(1) phg, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Nhanvien
GROUP BY phg
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks :) . I think about this once but I think there're even a better way than this. 
Thanks again :)